# node.js - can't access variables in mongoose save callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, callback

I am trying to save my data to mongodb using mongoose and then send json response.
This is my code

```
var userdata = {
  name: req.body.name,
  username: req.body.username,
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password,
};

var resdata = {};

var user = new User(userdata);
user.save(function (error) {
  if(error) {
    if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
      resdata =  { 
        status: false,
        errortype: 'db-error',
        message:  "Duplicate Key Error"
      };
    } else {

      resdata =  { 
        status: false,
        errortype: 'db-error',
        message:  error.message
      };
    }
  } else {

    resdata =  {
      status: true,
      message:  "User Registered Successfully.." 
    };
  }
});
res.send(resdata);
```

The problem is I cannot access the value of resdata outside the save callback. It always returns {}. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my full code
**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import router from './router';

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp');

// Initialize http server
const app = express();

// Logger that outputs all requests into the console
app.use(morgan('combined'));
// Use v1 as prefix for all API endpoints
app.use('/', router);

// Launch the server on port 3000
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  const { address, port } = server.address();
  console.log(`Listening at http://${address}:${port}`);
});
```

**router.js**

```
import express, { Router } from 'express';
// Import register action from movies controller
import register  from './controllers/register';
import validator from 'express-validator';

// Initialize the router
const router = Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
router.use(validator());

// Handle /movies.json route with register action from movies controller
router.post('/register', register.registerUser);

export default router;
```

**register.js**

```
  import mongoose from 'mongoose';
  import User from '../models/user';

  // Connect to MongoDB
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp', {useMongoClient: true});

  exports.registerUser = function(req, res) {

    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email does not appear to be valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

    // check the validation object for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    console.log(errors);

    var resdata = {};

    if (errors) {

      resdata =  { 
        status: false,
        errortype: 'validation',
        message:  errors 
      };

      res.send(resdata);
    } else {

      var userdata = {
        name: req.body.name,
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
      };

      var user = new User(userdata);
      user.save(function (error) {

        var resdata = {};
        if(error) {
          if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
            resdata =  { 
              status: false,
              errortype: 'mongoose-error',
              message:  "Duplicate Key Error"
            };
          } else {

            resdata =  { 
              status: false,
              errortype: 'mongoose-error',
              message:  error.message
            };
          }
        } else {

          resdata =  {
            status: true,
            message:  "User Registered Successfully.." 
          };
        }

        res.send(resdata);
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: that's what I told you to do from from the beginning `send data in the save callback`

Comment: yeah.. but it is still not sending any response when inside callback

Comment: don't know why but the code is working now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You have to send data to the client in the query's callback, here is an example:

```
user.save(function (error) {
    if(error) {
        if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {

            res.json({
                status: false,
                errortype: 'db-error',
                message:  "Duplicate Key Error"
            });

        } else {

            res.json({
                status: false,
                errortype: 'db-error',
                message:  error.message
            });
        }
    } else {

        res.json({
            status: true,
            message:  "User Registered Successfully.." 
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: I have thought of it but is there any way i could send the data outside the callback?

Comment: `User.save()` is asynchronous, that's mean you should wait until the query done and then send your response based on its result (i.e if there was an error or not)

Comment: Read this [article](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/) to understand the asynchronous nature of nodejs

Comment: the res variable is not working inside the callback. No response returned

Comment: are you using save method inside express middleware ? please show the whole code